# How can I call a function after all ajax calls have loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am using AngularJS. In a controller I called many ajax calls. After all data fetched from DB using ajax calls, I want to call a function. How can I  do that?

Comment: you might explore `$q.all()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to make your ajax calls, you can retrieve promises from those calls, and execute something when all calls ends with [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
var promises = [];
promises.push($http.get('1'));
promises.push($http.get('2'));
promises.push($http.get('3'));

$q.all(promises).then(function (datas) {
    // all 3 ajax calls have returns
    // you can even retrieve datas from each ajax calls
    var data1 = datas[0];
    var data2 = datas[1];
    var data3 = datas[2];
});
```

Comment: You can also use an object instead of an array, your result will be an object then too